# Programming several IEnumerators in c#

Tags: c#, list, collections, ienumerator

I have to program a generic collection in c#. I have this class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Pract_03
{
class Collection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    List<T> list;

    public Collection()
    {
        list = new List<T>();
    }
    public void Add(T item)//add element to collection
    {
        list.Add(item);
    }
    public bool Remove(T item) 
    {
        return list.Remove(item);
    }
    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return list.Contains(item);

    }
    public void Clear() 
    {
        list.Clear();

    }
    public int Count()
    {
        return list.Count;
    }
    public void Ordenar(IComparer<T> comparer) 
    {
        list.Sort(comparer);
    }
    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return list[index];
        }
    }


// This part was automatically added by visual studio, I'm not sure what it is
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable<T>)lista).GetEnumerator();
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable<T>)lista).GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have 2 IEnumerators: "EnumeratorForward" and "EnumeratorBackward", that iterate the colecction in one or other direction in the order that items were added.

Here the code of one of them, the other is analogous:

```
class EnumeratorForward<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    Collection<T> col;
    int index;

    public EnumeratorForward(Collection<T> collection)
    {
        col = collection;
        index = -1;

    }
    public T Current
    {
        get
        {
            return col[index];
        }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get
        {
            return col[index];
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        index++;
        if (index >= col.Count()) return false;
        else return true;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        index=-1;
    }
}
```

I don't even know if this implementation is correct. If I am not wrong IEnumerators in c# are like Iterators in java.

Well I have both enumerators. Now my problem, I need two more enumerators that iterate the collection with items in order. In conclusion, if I have the list [2,3,5,1,4]

enumeratorForward will do -> 2,3,5,1,4

enumeratorBackward        -> 4,1,5,3,2

enumeratorGreater         -> 1,2,3,4,5

enumeratorLess            -> 5,4,3,2,1

The problem is if I order the list of Collection I lose the order the items were added.

I dont know how could I implement that.

Comment: Aren't you reinventing the wheel? Linq already implements all those enumerators

Comment: *The problem is if I order the list of Collection I lose the order the items were added.* You have to create a copy of the Collection, sort the copy and enumerate on this copy. (both for enumeratorGreater and enumeratorLess)

Comment: @KooKiz Given the namespace he used (*Pract_03*) I'll say that he is trying some exercises...

Comment: @xanatos I was thinking the same thing...

Comment: Enumerators in C# are like iterators in Java, but they can be written a lot more easily with `yield return`. You only need a few lines to implement these ones.

Comment: @KooKiz I'm not reinventing nothing. I am learning. I just told you what my professor ask to do. I dont know Linq yet.

Comment: @KooKiz: If I remember well, LINQ's ops are not optimized for sources supporting random-access. It's not uncommon to provide your own At or Reverse implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Juan, listen to what you have said:

```
enumeratorForward will do -> 2,3,5,1,4
enumeratorBackward -> 4,1,5,3,2
enumeratorGreater -> 1,2,3,4,5
enumeratorLess -> 5,4,3,2,1

The problem is if I order the list of Collection I lose the order the items were added.
```

You've got numbers added in some order. But the numbers can be greater or lesser than each other. `3` is smaller than `5`, but `5` could have been added before `3`. Sure.

But how would you like to have them **ordered** by **both** their weight, and the order of addition? Let's see it for:

```
2,5,3,13,4,5,6,3,4,3
```

So.. '2' is first, sure. But in the output, should we have then '5' or '3'..? 5 occurs sooner, but 3 is the next higher than 2..

You have to say which score/rank/whatyoucallit is more important. For example, you can say: sort them by weight, and if some are equal, then sort them by adding-order. But that's somewhat nonsense for numbers. If 3 is equal to 3, then it's 3 and 3, and that's the same as 3 and 3, even if you swa them it's still 3 and 3.

```
2,(3,3,3),(4,4),(5,5),6,13
   \ | /   \ /   \ /
    which one is which one from the input?
      who cares, it's still 3, 4 and 5.
```

It starts having sense when
- your elements are more complex than numbers
- your ordering-equality is not a plain greater-equal-lesser

Ie. Let's assume you define that first rank is "even numbers first", then by "adding order"

```
 (2,4,6,4),  (5,3,13,5,3,3)
  \     /     \          /
 all even       all odd
  x%2==0         x%2==1
then in-order   then in-order of appearance
```

In the above example they are sorted by %2 value (0 or 1) then by order of appearance in the source list. Now it has some sense. Another example is sorting a list of "Person" objects. You can sort them by FamilyName, but when equal, sort them additionally by FirstName, and when equal again, leave the order of appearance (so MarySue from Spain will appear before MarySue from Germany like on the input list).

Even so, please note how I specify the sorting all the time: order by FOO then if equal by BAR then by (...) then by (...)

You simply cannot have anything ordered by 2 or more ranks at once. Some of them must be more important than other, and lower-importance ranks must be used only if the higher-importance ranks say that "items are equal".

If you want to implement some smart iterators that will reorder the list according to some ranking criteria, you will need something very similar to:
- a way to specify all criteria before actual sorting or iteration occurs
- a way to collect those criteria and pass them to sorting algorithm
- a way to execute the multi-criteria sorting
- a way to let the user iterate through the results

So, at the very least, you'd need several methods that say what will happen:
- GetEnumerator_ByOddEven
- GetEnumerator_ByOddEven_ThenAppearance
- GetEnumerator_ByOddEven_ThenGreater_ThenAppearance
etc, or:
- GetEnumerator(condition1, condition2, condition3, ...)
to pass all at once..

You can see another solution in LINQ .OrderBy(Desc) and .ThenBy(Desc) methods:
- .OrderBy returns an "OrderedEnumerable" that knows what's the first level of sorting and iterates according to it
- .ThenBy returns an "OrderedEnumerable" (a new one!) that will now know that for each so-far-equal there should be another round of sorting
- calling more .ThenBys returns again an "OrderedEnumerable" (a new one!) that will now know that there are 3,4,5,6... levels of sorting